# How to go back to same recyclerview item position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using a recyclerview which loads items from firebase database. On clicking the item, a new activity opens and displays the data. But when I return to the recyclerview activity, it opens from the top and not from the position I left from. How to implement opening activity from the left position.

The onBindViewHolder goes like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull MainModel model) {
        holder.headi.setText(model.getHeading());
        holder.arti.setText(model.getArticle());
        holder.date.setText(model.getPublishedDate());
        holder.user.setText(model.getUsername());

        Glide.with(holder.img.getContext())
                .load(model.getImageUrl())
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .into(holder.img);
        holder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent= new Intent(context, Read.class);
                intent.putExtra("Heading",model.getHeading());
                intent.putExtra("Article",model.getArticle());
                intent.putExtra("ImageUrl",model.getImageUrl());
                intent.putExtra("PublishedDate", model.getPublishedDate());
                intent.putExtra("PublishedBy", model.getUsername());
                context.startActivity(intent);
                ((Activity)context).finish();
            }
        });

    }
```

The back button in the Read activity goes like this:

```
public void back(View view)
 {
     if (fAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null)
 {
     i= new Intent(Read.this,Scroll2.class);
 }
 else{
     i= new Intent(Read.this,Scroll.class);
 }
     startActivity(i);
     finish();
 }
```

Comment: Not enough info here. Probably should post some code.

Comment: Added some code. Comprehendable now?

Comment: this is indeed a strange navigation pattern, get rid of the call to `finish()` in your `onClick` handler, and remove the call to `startActivity()` in your `back()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First store the visible top item position in `onPause()` of your Activity

```
 int lastPosition =  ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

Save it by using `savedInstanceState` and restore in `onResume()` by using

```
((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPositionWithOffset(lastPosition,0);
```

Comment: What purpose will, storing the first item position, serve?

Comment: @DevTiwari, your question in general is about saving and restoring state in an Activity, this proposed answer provides some guidance on doing that

Comment: @DevTiwari You can restore it and scroll to that position when activity is resumed

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Will try to figure out something different :)